# Adding an "inner glow" to a page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an inner glow to a whole page using CSS.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    background-image: url('/images/bg.png');
}
```

That half-works. The inner glow is there but it doesn't stretch to the whole height of the page.

http://snapplr.com/g65v.png

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What should happen when the page's height is greater than the window height?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `body` element doesn't fill the window.

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try switching the `body` to `html` , e.g. :

```
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
background-image: url('/images/bg.png');
}
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/LUREm/

Comment: Most of those styles should still be on the body element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LUREm/34/  problem arrises when you actually have content on the page.